# How to update a whole record in sequelize (not just single field)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I know how to update a particular field in **sequalize**

```
Project.update(
    {
        title: 'a new value'
    },
    {
        where: {id: 1}
    })
    .success(function () {
    })
    .error(function () {
    }
);
```

However, I would like to update a whole row of values/fields.

```
{
"field1":"foo",
"field2":"bar",
"field3":"bar2"
}
```

The documentation on the website is not very clear :
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/

Comment: Yes, I that's how to update an entire row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass an object with new data as first parameter to update function

```
Project.update(
{
    title: 'a new value',
    field1: "foo",
    field2: "bar"
},
{
    where: {id: 1}
})
```